# Want taskbar and Alt-Tab switcher to appear on two different monitors (Win 11)

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, taskbar, alt-tab

I have two monitors- primary/landscape/central and secondary/portrait/to-the-left. I would like the Windows 11 taskbar permanently on the left monitor while keeping the alt-tab switcher on the central monitor. (or both)

If I make the left monitor "primary" in windows then I get the taskbar correct, but alt-tab also moves there. I know about Win+Tab but I want a purely keyboard task swap and as far as I can tell, I need to use my mouse to pick a window in that scenario (arrow keys work, but only on the monitor windows thinks is "primary", which is the left one in this case)

I know you can, in theory, move the taskbar in Win11 via registry key but all the sites for that key (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3) only discuss the position, not which monitor it's on :/ I even checked to see if that key changes when I set the primary display but it doesn't appear to, even though I understand that in Win10 you could drag it to another monitor intentionally.

Any ideas? :)